# How can a session variable hold a record from database?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm still learning ASP.NET and I've been trying to find an answer online for my question but I couldn't find any related to what I wanted. So, my question is:

Is there a way for a Session variable to hold a record from database and then be used to access only some of the columns from it ? Kinda like this:

```
Session["Student"] = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentNumber == studentNumber);
Session["Student"].SingleOrDefault().StudentId;
```

Comment: Your session variables could be an object.  Then when you need to read the variable, you need to convert from the object to whatever type it is.  So a class or something similar.

Comment: @Brad thank you for your comment. I tried this `Session["Student"] = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentNumber == studentNumber);
var s = (Student)Session["Student"];
lblStudentName.Text = s.StudentId.ToString();` 

but I get this error: 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Test.Models.Student]' to type 'Test.Models.Student'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because this:

`Session["Student"] = db.Students.Where(x => x.StudentNumber == studentNumber);`

does not store a Student in your Session variable. It saves a query in session. Change it to `Session["Student"] = db.Students.Single(x => x.StudentNumber == studentNumber);` or `Session["Student"] = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StudentNumber == studentNumber);`

to achieve what you're looking for.

As a side note, you should probably do some null reference checks before you try to store the object in session and also when you retrieve it before using it. More like this:

```
var student = db.Students.SingleOrDefault(x => x.StudentNumber == studentNumber);
if(student != null)
{
   Session["Student"] = student;
}
```

And getting it back out:

```
var student = (Student)Session["Student"];
if(student != null)
{
   // do something with the student
}
```

And finally, there is almost certainly a better way to do what you want without using session variables.

Comment: Matt M thank you very much for your time, this is exactly what I was looking for.